# Workflow to to use displacement map for 3d printing

Tags: displacement

[image: example]

I'm trying to figure out designing a part that would be 3d printed and painted, my goal is to texturize surfaces without modelling each detail that costs a lot of time.
What is the correct workflow to realize pattern like these obtaining an stl for 3d printing?
Thanks in advice.
Enzo

Comment: I would sculpt the details using an image texture. Here's a tutorial detailing what I mean: https://youtu.be/Y8IEt-a6AnU